# Another way to write HAVING EVERY and HAVING ANY in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the enames of managers who manage only departments with budgets larger than 1 million, but at least one department with budget less than 5 million

I understand that the query should work like this but can not get it to run in Mysql. Im guessing because Every and Any in the having do not work in mysql. Is there any alternate way to write this? Also here is the schema

```
Emp(eid: integer, ename: string, age: integer, salary: real) 
Works(eid: integer, did: integer, pct_time: integer) 
Dept(did: integer, dname: string, budget: real, managerid: integer)
```

And here is the query:

```
select 
  e.ename 
from 
  emp e, dept d 
where 
  e.eid=d.managerid 
group by 
  e.eid, e.ename 
having 
  every(d.budget>1000000) and 
  any(d.budget<5000000);
```

Comment: You're using an implicit join -- note that Martin Smith is using an explicit join.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT e.ename
FROM   emp e
       JOIN dept d
         ON e.eid = d.managerid
GROUP  BY e.eid,
          e.ename
HAVING MIN(d.budget) > 1000000
       AND MIN(d.budget) < 5000000;
```

Comment: I am not getting back the right result pool with this. I am getting back an empty set.

Comment: @user964381 - Presumably you don't have any managers meeting that criteria then.

Comment: @James - No it shouldn't be a left join. If employees don't manage any departments they definitely won't meet the criteria to be included in the results.

Comment: @user964381 - The solution is fine. Not sure where you got that idea. If you aren't getting any results then for all your managers either of the following must be true. (1) They manage a department with budget <= 1million or (2) The smallest budget they manage is >= 5m.